# Dependent JARS for producing RESTful JSON

Tags: json, rest

I have written a RESTful service in java and want to produce json out of the get method.  I was struggling with many no class def found error due to issues in jar versions or dependencies.

**For example**
Jackson error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Versioned

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonMappingException$Reference

I have created a dynamic web project in eclipse and added the jars in classpath and Maven is not used here.

Any idea on the list of dependent jars ??

Comment: If you want to post a self-answer question, please post it in a Q&A format. Ask an actual question, then post an answer to it. Otherwise this post is off-topic and should be closed. Thanks

Comment: Done @peeskillet!!

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the jar versions and dependencies

[image]